# S_IFLNK, S_IFMT, and PATH_MAX undefined

Tags: c++, centos, vtk

I am using Centos 7 and am trying to install VTK as outlined [here](http://kris.kalish.net/2013/12/building-vtk-itk-itpp-and-boost-on-centos-6-5/).

When I run

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

I get

```
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

When I try

```
sudo yum groups mark install
```

I get

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Error: Need a group or list of groups
```

This part runs with no errors.

```
sudo yum remove cmake
sudo yum install qt qt4 qt4-designer
```

However,

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/cmake/cmake-2.8.8-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
```

did not connect so I downloaded cmake-2.8.8-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm and ran

```
sudo yum install cmake-2.8.8-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
```

successfully.

```
wget http://www.vtk.org/files/release/5.8/vtk-5.8.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf vtk-5.8.0.tar.gz
cd VTK
sudo ccmake .
# Press c to configure
# Set type to "Release"
# Enable qt
# Press c
# Press g
```

all ran successfully.  However, when I run

```
make -j `nproc`
```

I get

```
[  2%] [  2%] Building C object     Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/CMakeFiles/vtkhdf5.dir/H5Omtime.c.o
Building C object     Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/CMakeFiles/vtkhdf5.dir/H5Tfloat.c.o
[  2%] Built target vtkCommon
/home/peter/Downloads/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/H5F.c: In function     ‘H5F_build_actual_name’:
/home/peter/Downloads/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/H5F.c:2224:12: error:     ‘S_IFLNK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if(S_IFLNK == (lst.st_mode & S_IFMT)) {
        ^
/home/peter/Downloads/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/H5F.c:2224:12: note:     each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/peter/Downloads/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/H5F.c:2224:38: error: ‘S_IFMT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if(S_IFLNK == (lst.st_mode & S_IFMT)) {
                                  ^
/home/peter/Downloads/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/H5F.c:2229:27: error: ‘PATH_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         char realname[PATH_MAX];    /* Fully resolved path name of file */
```

I looked at /home/peter/Downloads/VTK/Utilities/vtkhdf5/src/H5F.c

and those strings are indeed used but not defined.

Comment: Is there any special reason that you want to bake VTK from source and not just using pre-built binary available in yum repo?

Comment: Good point!  yum install worked perfectly.  Thanks.